# How to change Button Title Alignment in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to set the title on a Button to left. But everything i tried is not working.

With:

```
UILabelButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Left
```

Or:

```
UILabelButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment // There is no left
```

The button title is still centered.

Is there another Property?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Use `contentHorizontalAlignment`.You have to use `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left`.You need to use`horizontal` not `vertical`.

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
```

Swift 3.x

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Comment: @codester .center doesn't seem to work if the text/content of a button is wrapped around to two lines. How can we centralise both lines of a button whose titleLabel has wrapped?

Answer (score 26):

## Swift 4

Sample code

For my requirement I want alignment **left** **top**

```
btnAddress.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left
btnAddress.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.top
```

## Swift 5 update:

```
btnAddress.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControl.ContentHorizontalAlignment.left
btnAddress.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.top
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the below solution (using Storyboard)

step1 :

set the horizontal alignment to left
[image]

By default button property have left content inset set to 10 i.e padding for the button from left side

you can see in the below image the left content inset is set to 10 for Left
so change that to 0, if you don't need any padding from left or set the number you want

[image]

This way you can set the button title to Left aligned

Answer (score 2):

```
    btnAddress.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControl.ContentHorizontalAlignment.left
    btnAddress.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.top
```

And now if you want the text to have some space from left add this

`btnAddress.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

like this with swift 4:

```
btnAddress.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score -1):

**The Most Easiest and smallest Solution:**

```
Button("0"){}.frame(width:160.0,height:70.0,alignment:Alignment.leading)
```

**Check this by using this code for a button you will see that button text is now aligned to "LEFT"**

[image: Button with text Alignment LEFT]